# Idle User Auto Logout in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout, idle-timer

I am currently working on a financial application that requires auto-logout when a user has been idle or away from the site/browser on given time.

This requirement might be similar to other questions posted here and other forums, but the app I am working on has a unique requirement because of existing functionalities.  These are the current app setup and functionalities:

1. Asp.net app using form authentication with session timeout set
2. App uses iFrames
3. App could opens multiple window to display different screens
4. App has heartbeat service (using js & ajax request) to monitor events (like incoming message)

I've been trying a lot of way on how I could implement the idle timeout js/jquery scripts based on answers and techniques mentioned in the forums. But with above existing functionalities, not sure what will be the best way to implement the idle timeout.

Any idea guys?